# pandas interpolations does not work for date index

Tags: python, pandas

I mocked the following data in a file:

```
Date,price
20010101,1
20010102,
20010104,4
```

Then to load this, I used

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_path", parse_dates=["Date"])
```

Neither the commands

```
df.interpolate("value")
df.interpolate("time")
```

worked. I expect the output to be

```
          price
Date     
20010101    1
20010102    2
20010104    4
```

ps. I forgot to say I did:

```
df.set_index("Date")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `time` method you need to set the date column as index.

```
df.set_index('Date').interpolate(method='time')
Out: 
            price
Date             
2001-01-01    1.0
2001-01-02    2.0
2001-01-04    4.0
```

Comment: URGH, when I did set_index("Date"), in did not do in place = True... thanks a lot